# Unix: Problem with cmp command

Tags: shell, shell-script

Let me give you an idea of what I am doing.

I am running a script that is doing basic OS processes for two systems Linux and SunOS. Well the first directory it runs is called sol0. The script puts the output of sol0 into a temp file.

It looks like this:

```
-----------------------
proc    1 response time =     67
proc    2 response time =    114
-----------------------
average response time   =     90
completion_time         =    170
total idle time         =     32
percent idle time       =     18%
-----------------------
```

I am editing the script to make a file in the current directory that stores sol0's output.
I want that file to compare to the output of every directory after that.

My cmp command says none of the outputs match even when I made a copy of sol0 with a different name. They both have the same output!

Here is how I am using the command ,but first some details about my script.

My Variables:

```
STUID=$1
PATH=${PATH}\:.
TMPFILE=tempfile
GDIR=`pwd`
OSNAME=`uname -s`
LOG=${GDIR}/results/${STUID}-${OSNAME}-X.log
DATE=`date`
TT=/dev/tty
file="./"
```

How the script is calling the function to run:

```
(  if [ ${OSNAME} = SunOS ] ; then
    ulimit 65
    ./sim >>${TMPFILE} 2>${TMPFILE}2 &

   else
    ulimit 35
    ./sim >>${TMPFILE} 2>${TMPFILE}2 &
   fi
  )
```

The cmd command:

```
if  [ ${STUID} = sol0 ]; then
    if  [ ${OSNAME} = SunOS ]; then 
          echo " Making SunOS compare file. " > ${TT}
          echo > ${GDIR}/compares
          echo " Created file. " > ${TT}
          cp ${TMPFILE} ${GDIR}/compares
    else
        echo " Making Linux compare file. " > ${TT}
    echo > ${GDIR}/comparel
    echo " Created file. " > ${TT}
    cp ${TMPFILE} ${GDIR}/comparel
    fi
  else
    echo " This is not sol0. " > ${TT}
  fi

  if [ ${OSNAME} = Linux ]; then
    if [ ${STUID} != sol0 ]; then
      if [ cmp ${TMPFILE} ${GDIR}/comparel ]; then
        echo "${STUID} Linux output matches the Linux output of sol0." > ${TT}
      else
        echo "${STUID} Linux output does not match the Linux output of sol0." >${TT}
      fi  
   else
      echo "This is sol0, no comparing will be done." >${TT}
   fi
  else
   echo "This is running on SunOS. " >${TT}
  fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking specifically at your `cmp` command, replace:

```
if [ cmp ${TMPFILE} ${GDIR}/comparel ]; then
```

With:

```
if cmp "${TMPFILE}" "${GDIR}/comparel"; then
```

One uses the `[` command (also known as `test`) when one wants to set an exit code according to one of various conditions (a file exists, a string is empty, etc.).  Here, you want to set an exit code based on the result of the `cmp` command and you have no use for `test`.  Therefore, the square brackets need to be removed.

Comment: Thank you for that knowledge, I did not know that. Are there any other reasons why it would not compare? My cmp specifically is still saying it wouldn't match, so I must be doing something wrong still.

Comment: @user2419571 Since, as I understand it, your files are text, my first suggestion is try to `diff` on the files instead of `cmp`.  The advantage of `diff` is that, if it thinks the files differ, it will show you exactly _why_ it thinks so.

Comment: @Jogn1024 You're awesome, thank you!